# Multivariable derivative question: Rudin theorem 9.19

Tags: real-analysis, multivariable-calculus, derivatives, proof-explanation

Rudin's definition of differentiability states the following:

> Suppose $E$ is an open subset of $\mathbb{R}^n$. Let $f: E \to
>  \mathbb{R}^m$ be a map. Let $x \in E$. We say that $f$ is
>   differentiable at $x$ if there is a linear transformation $A:
>  \mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}^m$ such that
>
> $$\lim_{h \to 0} \frac{\Vert f(x+h)-f(x)-Ah\Vert}{\Vert h \Vert} = 0$$

Later, the multivariable chain rule is proven:

> Suppose $E$ is an open subset of $\mathbb{R}^n$, $f$ is differentiable
>   at $x_0$, $g$ maps an open set containing $f(E)$ into $\mathbb{R}^k$,
>   and $g$ is differentiable at $f(x_0)$. Then the mapping $F$ of $E$
>   into $\mathbb{R}^k$ defined by $F(x) = g(f(x))$ is differentiable at
>   $x_0$ and $F(x_0) = g'(f(x_0))f'(x_0)$.

Theorem 9.19 states:

> Suppose $f$ maps an open convex set $E \subseteq \mathbb{R^n}$ into
>   $\mathbb{R}^m$, $f$ is differentiable on $E$, and there is a real
>   number $M \geq 0$ such that $\Vert f'(x) \Vert \leq M$ for all $x \in
>  E$. Then
>
> $$\Vert f(b)- f(a) \Vert \leq M \Vert b-a \Vert$$
>   for all $a, b \in \mathbb{R}^n$

This is the beginning of the proof:

> Fix $a, b\in E$. Define $\gamma(t) = (1-t)a + tb$ for all $t \in
> > \mathbb{R}$ such that $\gamma(t) \in E$. Since $E$ is convex,
>   $\gamma(t) \in E$ if $0 \leq t \leq 1$.
>
> Put $g(t):= f(\gamma(t))$.
>
> Then $g'(t) = f'(\gamma(t))\gamma'(t) = f'(\gamma(t))(b-a)$
>   so that $\Vert g'(t) \Vert \leq \Vert f'(\gamma(t)) \Vert\Vert b-a \Vert \leq M \Vert b-a \Vert$ for all $t \in [0,1]$ [and the proof continues...]

Apparently, the chain rule is used. However, mustn't the domain of $\gamma$ be an open subset of $\mathbb{R}$ in order to apply the chain rule? In particular, I can see that the conclusion might hold for $t \in (0,1)$, but what about $t=0, t=1?$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since $E$ is open, not only is $\gamma(t) \in E$ for $0 \le t \le 1$, there exists $\epsilon_0  > 0$ with the property that $\gamma(t) \in E$ for $-\epsilon \le t \le 1 + \epsilon$ whenever $0 < \epsilon < \epsilon_0$.

By your reasoning above, for any such $\epsilon$ you have $$\|\gamma'(t)\| \le M \|\gamma(1+\epsilon) - \gamma(-\epsilon)\|$$
if $-\epsilon < t < 1+\epsilon$, and in particular if $t \in [0,1]$. Since
$$\gamma(1+\epsilon) - \gamma(-\epsilon) = [- \epsilon a + (1+\epsilon)b] - [(1+\epsilon) a -\epsilon b] = (b-a) + 2\epsilon(b-a)$$ it follows that
$$\|\gamma'(t)\| \le M (\|b-a\| + 2\epsilon \|b-a\|)$$
for all $t \in [0,1]$. Now let $\epsilon \to 0^+$.

Comment: Thanks. Using the first line of your answer, can't we just define $\gamma$ on the domain $(- \epsilon_0, 1 + \epsilon_0)$? This is open, and contains $[0,1]$ as subset.

Comment: Also, does the first line of your answer follow from continuity of $\gamma$? I think I managed to prove that line using that preimage of open set is open.

Comment: Yes, the natural domain of $\gamma$ is an open set containing $[0,1]$. This is due to the fact $E$ is open, not the continuity of $\gamma$.

Comment: How do you justify your first line then without using continuity? My approach would be to notice that for $t=0$, we have $B(\gamma(t), \epsilon_0) \subseteq E$ for some $\epsilon_0 > 0$. By continuity, $\gamma^{-1}(B(\gamma(t), \epsilon_0))$ is open and this preimage contains $t$. Hence, there is $\delta_0>0$ such that $(t- \delta_0, t + \delta_0) \subseteq \gamma{-1}(E)$. In particular, $\gamma(t-\delta_0, t + \delta_0) \subseteq E$. Similarly for $t=1$. Here I considered $\gamma$ as a function on $\mathbb{R}$. Later it can be restricted to the appropriate (open) subset.